# Creating a MUC using Strophe JS and MUC plugin

Tags: javascript, strophe

I am trying to create muc using below code

```
 app.connection.muc.createInstantRoom("Hello", function(){ 
      console.log(arguments); 
 });
```

The above code is returning me `"1:sendIQ"`, what does it mean and I had a look at source of MUC js and it is expecting parameters like below

```
/*Function
   Parameters:
   (String) room - The multi-user chat room name.
   Returns:
     id - the unique id used to create the chat room.
*/

createInstantRoom: function(room, success_cb, error_cb) {
  var roomiq;
  roomiq = $iq({
     to: room,
     type: "set"
  }).c("query", {
     xmlns: Strophe.NS.MUC_OWNER
  }).c("x", {
     xmlns: "jabber:x:data",
     type: "submit"
  });
  return this._connection.sendIQ(roomiq.tree(), success_cb, error_cb);
}
```

As per the description mentioned above I thought it is roomID and I started sending invites like below

```
app.connection.muc.invite("Hello", "brainlessHeart@localhost");
```

Now this returns me `"18", "19", "20"` etc.. in each call. But at the `brainlessHeart@localhost` end nothing is received.

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Did you have any progress on that?

Comment: @EduardoXavier Yes, I missed the namespace. In ejabberd.cfg you have to mention the resource for MUC service. By the default it will be conference in Ejabberd in MongooseIM it would be MUC. Adding that has solved the issue.

Comment: how did you solve this problem?